# How land clearing would be done in this theoretical situation?

Tags: civil-engineering

Given the following fictious scenario:

A construction project requires that a big swampy landscape has to be cleared. This swamp landscape has various trees (also trees with a big diameter), a wet region that is a swamp, a lake and some rocks. A construction company has to clear all that things to build a theme park with big coasters and roads on this. Now I am interested in how this company would do this in a cost-saving and also fast way. How costs can be minimized without being too slow?

My idea:

1. Tree felling with chainsaw and then stump removal with excavator or pure removal of trees with excavators and/or bulldozers. The second version (version without felling trees before) is faster, but may require stronger machines (more costs?)
2. Rocks can be removed by excavators if rocks are small. Larger rocks must be blasted.
3. Excavators begin to dig holes around the swamp and the lake.
4. Now water can be removed from the lake and the swamp by a pipe inserted between the wet region and the holes.
5. The land must be made flat by bulldozers.

Is this procedure plausible in this fictious (it is not real) scenario?

Comment: "Is this reasonable?" is not a good question for this site. What problem do you have? Do you really just want to know how swamps are drained?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know how swamps are drained.

Comment: "Land clearing" is not the same as "draining".

Answer (score 1):

You plan appears plausible, but does the theme park really need to be located where there is now a lake?

The existence of a lake indicates that there is localized low elevation point on the landscape. Could this pose problems in the future with water inundation, or do you plan to have excellent water drainage infrastructure for such an event?

Relocating a lake seems expensive when dry land nearby can be used, if it is available.